# MySQL: INSERT... VALUES, INSERT... SET и гибридный вариант

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

При чтении легаси-кода обнаружил SQL-запрос к MySQL такого типа:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) 
     VALUES (field1 = value1, field1 = value2, field3 = value3 );
```

Насколько я понимаю, [в MySQL есть два варианта оформления запроса на вставку](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) (если не учитывать вариант с *INSERT... SELECT*):

(1)

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3)
     VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```

и (2)

```
INSERT INTO table SET field1 = value1, field2 = value2, field3 = value3;
```

Этот второй вариант, по-моему, очень хорош, если заполняемых запросом полей много - ты не привязан к порядку полей в таблице и видно, какое значение к какому полю относится.

Варианта, подобного примеру из легаси-кода я в мануале не увидел. Есть сильное подозрение, что помимо просто указания имени поля подобная конструкция может использоваться еще каким-то образом. Или же это просто избыточный код, который можно вычистить и привести либо к стандартному варианту (1) или [MySQL-специфичному варианту (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861722/mysql-insert-into-table-values-vs-insert-into-table-set)?

Comment: Такой штуки никогда не видел :

`INSERT INTO table SET field1 = value1, field2 = value2, field3 = value3;`

Зато вот такая есть :

`UPDATE table SET field1 = value1, field2 = value2, field3 = value3;`

Comment: @АндрейАршинов, теперь знаете )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для начала, выражение

```sql
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) 
 VALUES (field1 = value1, field1 = value2, field3 = value3 );
```

полностью валидно с точки зрения синтаксиса. Но именно в представленном виде, оно вставит в таблицу строчку `NULL`-ов.

---

Разберемся, что тут происходит. В первую очередь это никакой не "особый синтаксис" для указания значений конкретным столбцам. Это обычный `INSERT ... VALUES`.

Что там делают тогда `field1`, `field2` и `field3`? Дело в том, что внутри `VALUES(...)` допустимо ссылаться для задания значения столбца на значение другого столбца. Например, чтобы вставить в первый столбец значение `5`, во второй - в два раза больше, а в третий - в три раза больше чем во второй, можно написать:

```sql
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, field3) 
 VALUES (5, field1 * 2, field2 * 3);
```

---

Вернемся к исходному выражению. Зачем там для задания значения столбцов знак равенства? Очевидно: это операция сравнения. Значения столбцов задаются по порядку:

1. `field1 = value1`, поскольку столбец `field1` еще не задан, это равносильно `NULL = value1`. Сравнение с `NULL` всегда вернет `NULL`.
2. `field1 = value2`. Теперь `field1` уже явно выставлен в `NULL`. Результат, аналогичен, пункту 1.
3. `field3 = value3`, снова ситуация, как с первым столбцом.

В итоге всем трем столбцам мы присвоили `NULL`, что, вероятно, не соответствовало замыслу автора.

Answer (score -2):

Никакого "гибридного" варианта не существует. Обнаруженный код - это просто какая-то ошибка, его надо удалить.